# How to account for correlation in a pre-existing linear model?

Tags: correlation, linear-model

By using a pre-existing model we get weights $w_1, w_2 ... w_n$ assigned to $n$ variables. But the model does not take correlation between those $n$ variables into account. How can the correlation matrix $C$ between the $n$ variables be used to adjust the weights from the model?

Edit: The coefficients here are not obtained by linear regression but are the output from a series of optimizations. One further addition we want to do after optimization is take the correlation between the variables into account.

Answer (score 0):

Regression coefficients are partial correlation coefficients where correlation between variables is accounted for. Very large correlation between variables can lead into difficulties where individual marginal effect is almost impossible to estimate in precise way.

Comment: Yes that's right. The coefficients here are not obtained by linear regression but are the output from a series of optimizations. One further addition we want to do after optimization is take the correlation between the variables into account.

Comment: @web_ninja you have to make some changes to your question since I thought that this is about linear regression. Can you use some form of quadratic programming where covariance matrix is present in quadratic term t(x)Cx?

Comment: Yes that seems like a good idea. The optimization function would be to find W to minimize this: Distance(W-w_now) + W^T . C conflicted about using which distance measure : L1 distance or cosine similarity?

Comment: @web_ninja that dependents on your priorities. Covariance matrix or its inverse is often used..